# How to extract an array of expr from an expr_vector

Tags: z3

In order to use the following func_decl member c++ api:

```
expr operator()(unsigned n, expr const * args) const
```

I am looking for a way to transform an expr_vector in which I have all arguments to whom the function shall apply, into an array of expr.

What is the way? Would it make sense to add

```
expr operator()(expr_vector & args) const
```

in the c++ API ?

BR,
Alexandre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be using an older version of Z3; this function:

```
expr operator()(expr_vector const& v) const;
```

was already added to the code in the unstable branch of Z3.

Comment: I don't see it here:http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/classz3_1_1func__decl.html

Comment: The online documentation is for the master branch, it will be updated once unstable becomes the new master.